# Changing Gregorian Month and Days names to Islamic? NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I'm trying to display the Islamic current `day` name , `month` name. I used NSLocale to set the region to `ar_SA`, however it's just translating the day and month names from English to Arabic.

Output I'm getting in Arabic:

`١٢ الأحد ، اكتوبر ، ٢٠١٢`   which in English is `Sunday, October 28, 2012`

Output I want:

`Al-Ahad, Dul-Hijja 12, 1433`

Snippet:

```
NSDateFormatter *islamicFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[islamicFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[islamicFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_SA"]];
NSString *islamicDateString = [islamicFormatter stringFromDate:islamicDate];
NSLog(@"%@",islamicDateString);
```

I hope it's clear for you guys.

Comment: are hebrew date and arabic date same ?

Comment: Please excuse me. I checked the difference and it is totally different. Please check the answer below and let me know if that helps.

Comment: they are totally different :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this would help

```
NSCalendar * hijri = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSIslamicCalendar];

NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setCalendar:hijri];

NSLog(@"hijri: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: you can check the detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354337/hijri-islamic-calendar-problem

Comment: Actually I checked this answer before I posted my question. However, this code will only display the numeric date. dd/mm/yyyy . I think the key problem is in `NSDateFormatter` particularly in `setDateStyle`.

Comment: I knew it! I missed the `setCalendar` option. I feel stupid. Been checking the API for 4 hours and this was just right in front of my eyes! thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is quite old but I think it is necessary to add Swift 3 code as below for other reference.

```
let hijri = Calendar(identifier: .islamic)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = hijri
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"

let today = Date()
let dateString = formatter.string(from: today)

print(dateString)

// the output: 16 Jamada II 1438
```