# Gregorian to Hijri (vise versa)

Tags: swift, date, math, formula

The source code is come from

[Hijri (islamic) calendar in swift التاريخ الهجري](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034840/hijri-islamic-calendar-in-swift)

[How can I convert string date to NSDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777496/how-can-i-convert-string-date-to-nsdate)

I just put them together but it has some mistake with the output

```
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

    let GregorianDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(Yeartext1.text!)-\(Monthtext1.text!)-\(Daytext1.text!)")

    let islamic = NSCalendar(identifier: NSIslamicCalendar)

    let components = islamic?.components(NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max), fromDate: GregorianDate!)

    resultlable.text = "\(components!.year) - \(components!.month) - \(components!.day)"
```

For Example , the user will enter a gregorian date (2015/09/29) and it will show the Hijri year (1436/12/15) .

but the result in this code is wrong .

SO , Please help .

Thanks a lot for x4h1d (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1459192/x4h1d) , Grimxn  (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3729417/grimxn) and for everyone for help .

Comment: Don't just ask us to write code for you.  What have you tried?  Please post your work-in-progress Swift implementation.

Comment: I would set the locale to Gregorian, create a universal timestamp from the Gregorian input, set the locale to Hijri, then create Hijri output from the universal timestamp.

Comment: sorry guys but it is the first post for me . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSDate and NSDateFormatter for date conversions.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109905/changing-gregorian-month-and-days-names-to-islamic-nsdate) might help you.

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) also gives a lot of useful information.

Comment: Gregorian to Hijri (only) The right answer in this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893323/convert-gregorian-date-to-hijri-date